# Solving an equation with fractional laplacian

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, fractional-calculus

Let $s\in (0,1)$, how i can solve the equation:
$$ (-\Delta)^su=1,\quad\text{in}\quad(-1,1)?$$
I have no idea, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the equation on $\mathbb{R}$ or on $(-1,1)$ and then what are the boundary conditions?

Comment: The equation is on $\mathbb{R}$ and i want that $u=0$ in $\mathbb{R}\setminus(-1,1)$.

Comment: With the Fourier transform the equation is $ |k|^{2s}\hat{u}(k)=\frac{2\sin(k)}{k}$

Comment: Then i have to anti-transform the function $2\sin(k)/k|k|^{2s}$? How i can compute the Fourier anti-transform of this function? Can you give me the details please ?

Comment: @RaphaelB4 --- the inverse Fourier transform of the function $\hat{u}$ you wrote down is nonzero for $|x|>1$, while we seek a solution $u=0$ for $|x|>1$; the point is that we cannot assume that $\Delta^s u=0$ for $|x|>1$, we only know $\Delta^s u$ for $|x|<1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to
$$(-\Delta)^s u(x)=1,\;\;-1<x<1,
$$
with $u(x)=0$ for $|x|\geq 1$ is
$$
u(x)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}(1-x^2)^s }{4^{s}\Gamma(\tfrac{1}{2}+s)\Gamma(1+s)},$$
as follows from the [integral definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_Laplacian) of the fractional Laplacian.

<sub>$$\text{The $n$-dimensional generalization is} \qquad u(x)=\frac{\Gamma(n/2)(1-x^2)^s }{4^{s}\Gamma(\tfrac{n}{2}+s)\Gamma(1+s)}.$$</sub>

An early reference for this result is R. Getoor, [First passage times for symmetric stable processes in space](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1993412%0A) (1961) and a comment by Mateusz Kwaśnicki points to an earlier [paper](http://acta.bibl.u-szeged.hu/13487/1/math_009_001-042.pdf) by Marcel Riesz.

The OP asks for a simple derivation. A calculation using only elementary calculus is in [Some observations on the Green function for the ball in the fractional Laplace framework.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.06468)

Comment: I am puzzled with the case where $s\le\frac12$, because one does not expect the solution to vanish at both ends.

Comment: Noteworthy, for $s < \tfrac12$, the calculation essentially goes back to M. Riesz's 1938 paper, where it appeared in a rather disguised form. And I read once that the 1-D case was actually considered even earlier (by Weyl, perhaps?), but I fail to remember where I found that comment.

Comment: Is there a simple way for solve $(-\Delta)^su=1$?

Comment: @inoc --- I have given a reference to a "simple" calculation, although it is still lengthy; I have not found a simple and quick derivation.